# Prove inequality holds under given assumption…

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

In my real analysis class the professor used this inequality to solve a question, however, there was a *lack* of explanation. The inequality is the following:

Let $E$ be some set. Suppose $f(x) > 1$, for $x \in E$. Then the following holds:
$$\sqrt[3]{f(x)} \leq f(x).$$

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the fact that $x\le x^3$ when $x\ge 1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!